# Intall SQL Server 2008 On Windows Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We update our Server from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2016. And we use SQL Server 2008 R2 on the old server. I read from the website said that SQL Server 2008 is compatible with Windows 7, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista, and Windows XP.

Can I install SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2016? or a good way to this problem?

Thank You

Comment: I know SQL Server 2008 is EOL. but this project has been running since 2010. will the SQL 2008 upgrade change the query or data processing in it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if SQL Server 2008 can be run on Windows Server 2016.

I think a better solution will be upgrading to a supported version of SQL Server as 2008 is EOL since september 2019.
You can set the database [compability level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16) to behave as SQL 2008.

References:
[EOL SQL 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/end-support-sql-server-2008)